# Setting up Raspberry Pi Jessie to show node-red console after boot

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red

I'm no Linux expert unfortunately but hoping someone out there can help. I have a Raspberry Pi running Jessie with a screen HAT attached. This shows the console after boot sitting there at the logon prompt and I can log in and run node-red, which then shows node-red console data streaming by. I want to set it up so that it gets to that state after starting up with no user input i.e. no login required. 
node-red is sending data to the console via debug nodes and it's that data I want to display after power up with no user intervention.
I'd imagine I have to set it to login automatically to the user that node-red is running under (pi) but I have followed instructions to do that and the screen basically doesn't actually log in.
Thank you!

Comment: There are docs for how to auto-start on boot on the node-red website - http://nodered.org/docs/hardware/raspberrypi - that doesn't cover everything you ask (getting that console output on screen automatically) but it is a starting point

Answer (score 0):

use these -

For version 0.12.5 of Node-RED and later:

**sudo systemctl enable nodered.service**

For version 0.12.1 of Node-RED - SD card Jessie Nov 2015:

**sudo update-rc.d nodered defaults**

just copy/paste the  suitable command  for your system.

hope it helps !